# Mark menu item selected on push in Flutter app

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Flutter app there is Drawer that shows menu items.

Selected menu item has different color, I handle it storing selectedItemIndex in Drawer. I want to solve two issues:

1. When app receives push notification it changes screen so now selectedItemIndex should be changed outside Drawer.
2. Routes that are used while handling push notifications are almost similar to routes used in Drawer menu. So I want to avoid code duplication.

What way of storing and updating selectedMenuIndex as well as handling routes should be used in Flutter?

[image]